# Associate a custom user agent to a specific Google Chrome page/tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, user-agent

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension and I'd like to set up a specific user agent to a tab/page, or to a popup (iframe shown as a "bubble popup"), without affecting other pages or tabs.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`webRequest` API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html) can be used to modify the User Agent header.
Note: The Network tab at the Developer tools show the **old** headers. I've verified that the headers are set correctly, using [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) (`nc -l 127.0.0.1 -p 6789`).

In the example below, the code activates on **all** tabs. Adjust the [request filter](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#type-RequestFilter) to meet your requirements. Add `tabId` to limit the functionality to this filter, with the tabId of your tabs (obtainable through various APIs, [`chrome.tabs`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) in particular).

### `background.js`

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(info) {
        // Replace the User-Agent header
        var headers = info.requestHeaders;
        headers.forEach(function(header, i) {
            if (header.name.toLowerCase() == 'user-agent') { 
                header.value = 'Spoofed UA';
            }
        });  
        return {requestHeaders: headers};
    },
    // Request filter
    {
        // Modify the headers for these pages
        urls: [
            "http://stackoverflow.com/*",
            "http://127.0.0.1:6789/*"
        ],
        // In the main window and frames
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
    },
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);
```

### `manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "WebRequest UA test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "http://*/*"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

### Documentation

- [`chrome.webRequest.onbeforeSendHeaders`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeSendHeaders) event
- The [Request filter](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#type-RequestFilter)