# Send XHR request from Chrome extension with cookies

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send an XHR request from a Google Chrome extension to another domain. This would work fine, but I need to send that domains cookies with the request. Any way to do this?

Comment: You can use the [`webRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeSendHeaders) API to modify headers, including `Cookie`. An example of UA spoofing + header editing can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10339902/938089?associate-a-custom-user-agent-to-a-specific-google-chrome-page-tab).

Comment: Why are you under the impression that Chrome will not send the user's cookies? I just tested it, and it does. Is the site in your permissions?

Comment: Huh. My bad. It definitely does send cookies with the request.

Comment: What ajax library are you guys doing? jQuery isn't sending it..do I need to use native XHR or something?

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the `manifest.json` **permissions** are **setup properly**.

You have to properly set the cross site domain request permission in the `manifest.json` of your chrome extension. When done properly, the cookies who are already set for the targeted domain will be sent along with the request you are making to that domain. [manifest.json documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)

You have to be especially careful when playing with `localhost:port_number`. You will need to specify that domain in full in the `manifest.json` for it to work. I ended up with awkward behaviors when my localhost domain was NOT specify in full.

This is how you want to specify your localhost domain in the `manifest.json` of your extension (if that makes sense):

```
...
"permissions": [
    "http://localhost:3000/"
  ],
...
```

If the cookies you want to send to the targeted domain are not set yet, you can do so my using  the `chrome.cookies.set` method and specify the domain name you want through the object `domain` attribute you pass to the `set` method. The documentation is here: [chrome.cookies.set](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html#method-set).

Comment: Why does localhost give cross site permissions?

Comment: I have problem with "incognito". Chrome uses "normal mode cookies", how to use "incognito cookies" for that mode?

Comment: you also want to make sure the cookie path match, what I found out is a cookie set at path `/a` won't be sent to url `/b`; a cookie set at path `/` will be sent to all urls under same domain though.