# Chrome extension API webRequest doesn't work well on response

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying the Chrome API webRequest. Everything works fine on request, but on response, I got problems.

My testing is pretty straight forward:

```
function func(obj)
{
    var resHeaders=obj.responseHeaders;
    for(var i=0;i<resHeaders.length;i++)
    {
        if(resHeaders[i].name=="X-Powered-By" && resHeaders[i].value.indexOf("PHP")>=0)
        {
            resHeaders[i].value="Extension";
            resHeaders.push({name:"X-Test",value:"Found"});
            chrome.pageAction.show(obj.tabId);
            break;
        }
    }
    return {responseHeaders:resHeaders};
}

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(func,{urls:["<all_urls>"]},["blocking","responseHeaders"]);
```

---

> To my surprise, Chrome Developer Tool always shows the original header
>   even though the header is correctly modified (I have to use
>   `XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders()` to tell). This is very
>   inconvenience because I have to made many XHR to debug instead of
>   trying on real world webpages.

**Edit**: Confirmed by @RobW, this is a bug, so it belongs to crbug.com...

---

The bigger problem is, if the modification is not made on the last request that before the load event, the pageAction icon would not show up.

E.g.
If a page contains four requests:

> HTML -> triggers modification
>
> CSS
>
> JS
>
> [Load event]
>
> HTML inside `iframe` -> triggers modification

pageAction icon stays;

But if a page contains three requests:

> HTML -> triggers modification
>
> CSS
>
> JS
>
> [Load event]

pageAction icon would show up and disappear (I can see this on a slow XP machine; on fast machine it just doesn't show up).

But if I then hand made an XHR (triggers the modification), the pageAction icon correctly stays on address bar.

This problem is annoying because I have to let the user (if any) know that the extension is in effect.

---

Same thing happened on Win 7 and XP, latest Chrome (21+, stable). Is this expected, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is indeed a bug. Four months ago, I [also encountered this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10339902/938089). Report the bug at http://new.crbug.com/ if you want it to be fixed (I wasn't able to find a duplicate).

Comment: @RobW Thanks. While that's very inconvenient, it's still debug-able. But what about the second problem (pageAction icon disappears)?

Comment: Does `obj.tabId` hold an expected value (not `-1`?). Throw in some `console.log`s, and watch the background page.

Comment: @RobW Yes the `obj.tabId` does hold expected value. I `console.log(obj.tabId+": "+JSON.stringify(resHeaders))` several times before posting this question.

Comment: The WebRequest API is activated before a page is actually rendered (important in the case of `main_frame`). It might be possible that the page unloads after the `webRequest` API has finished. When a page unloads, the pageAction icon is removed. If this is true, using `setTimeout(function(){chrome.pageAction.show(obj.tabId);}, 1000);` would show the page action about 1 second after the headers were received (no guarantee about the response body!). Rather than hacking around with delays, you can bind a `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event.

Comment: @RobW I tested this on my localhost where I hand make all pages......Anyway, `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` does seem to be able to work around this problem (caches an `var showIconTabId={}` in `background.js` and use `tabs.onUpdated` to refresh it). I'll try that. Many thanks.