# Chrome User agent doesn't change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, user-agent

I have a chrome extension to show the Google Translate easier to the user. There is an option if user wants to see the translate in a new windows or not. To showing the translate page in a new windows I want to show the user a compact translate page. I want to change USER-AGENT to show the user Google Translate's mobile version.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334909/associate-a-custom-user-agent-to-a-specific-google-chrome-page-tab) and this is my function to open the new windows but the windows's user agent doesn't change and I don't know how can I resolve the problem:

```
function OpenURL(url, tab)
{

    if(config.tab=="true")
    {
        var id = tab.index +1;
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': url, 'index': id});
    }
    else
    {
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
        function(info) {
            // Replace the User-Agent header
            var headers = info.requestHeaders;
            headers.forEach(function(header, i) {
                if (header.name.toLowerCase() == 'user-agent') { 
                    header.value = 'Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10';
                }
            });  
            return {requestHeaders: headers};
        },
        // Request filter
        {
            // Modify the headers for these pages
            urls: [
                "*translate.google.com*",
            ],
            // In the main window and frames
            types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
        },
        ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
        );
        newwindow = window.open(url, "_blank", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes");
    }
}
```

Can anyone Help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"*translate.google.com*",` is an invalid [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html), try
`"*://translate.google.com/*"` instead.