# Changing User-Agent in XMLHttpRequest from a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send a HTTP request from a Extension in which I need to change the User-Agent.

My code looks like this:

```
function getXMLHttpRequest(method, url, extraHeaders) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true)

    for (var headerKey in extraHeaders) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(headerKey, extraHeaders[headerKey]);
    }

    return xhr;
}
//....

getXMLHttpRequest("POST", "....", { "User-Agent": "Blahblahblah" })
```

Then, I get an error **"Refused to set unsafe header: UserAgent"**

I need to change that because my Backend needs to have an special User-Agent, is it possible to do that from an extension?

I tried webRequest API, to change the header before sending the request, but it says it does not work with XMLHttpRequest made from extensions in order to prevent locking.

Comment: @ExpertSystem But you can change the UserAgent using the webRequest API. It is one of its examples in the doc. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html

Comment: @ExpertSystem I know it is considered unsafe, but this is not a regular javascript, it is a browser extension, I can use sockets and send whatever I want. Why not allowing to send an arbitrary HTTP Request? Cross-Origin request are also forbidden by the standards and they can be done with the proper configuration in the manifest.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ This one describes how you cannot make a HTTP request to a webserver which does not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response for OPTIONS. I haven't changed my server and I can make XMLHttpRequests to destionations which does not include that header in the response. But anyway, I'm not saying XMLHttpRequest should allow it, I'm asking for a way to make a HTTP Request specifying my own User-Agent inside a chrome extension. It can be a chrome.* API or whatever.

Comment: I removed my comment above, because they were useless. I was pretty sure I had read it in the docs, but apparently I was wrong. (Sorry, for the confusion !)

Answer (score 7):

You can easily change the User-Agent header with the `webRequest` API.
For sample code, see [Associate a custom user agent to a specific Google Chrome page/tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334909/associate-a-custom-user-agent-to-a-specific-google-chrome-page-tab/10339902#10339902).

Take the code from that answer, and change `"main_frame", "sub_frame"` to `"xmlhttprequest"` to modify network requests initiated via `XMLHttpRequest`.

Obviously, to prevent deadlocks, this method does **not** work with **synchronous** requests ( i.e. when the third parameter of `xhr.open` is set to `false`).

Comment: Hey, Rob, was it always like that ? I remember having read somewhere in the docs about the limitation on unsafe XMLHttpRequest headers applying to a chrome.* API as well, but I can't find it any more. Any insights ? Am I out of my mind ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem There's a list indeed, but "User-Agent" is not a part of it. Scroll a bit down at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#life_cycle to see a partial list of hidden headers. The list is unfortunately "not guaranteed to be complete nor stable", so to get a definite answer, one has to dig deep in Chromium's source code.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the list, but remember some doc explicitely saying that the same "unsafe" headers as XHR are also preventing. OK, then I am probably loosing it. BTW, you always spook me with your Chromium's-source-code-digging stuff :)

Comment: @RobW what's the scope of the code you linked to (assuming `types` is changed to `xmlhttprequest`)? Will it affect ALL XMLHttpRequests initiated by the browser, both inside and outside the extension? I understand it will also be filtered by the specified URL, just curious about the scope.

Comment: @figs All XMLHttpRequests. But you use can choose to return nothing in order, and/or use `.removeListener` instead of `addListener` to unregister an event (example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23001552)

Comment: @RobW Hi, Rob, I have many doubts I want to clear, and reading your answers made me feel that you can help me with my queries, can we have a little chat ?