# `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener`? -- How to stop a chrome web listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I was checking out the sample code for the CatBlock extension sample for `chrome.webrequest`, and I saw that it opened the listener with

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener
```

So when I want to close it, can I just do

`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener`?

If not, how would I get rid of it?

I think this is similar to Javascript's native event listener, but I know the one used in Chrome's extensions is a little different.

Thanks!

evamvid

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First off, full documentation [is available here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events).

`addListener` function normally<sup>1</sup> has one argument, the function that will be executed as a callback when the event fires.

One can pass a named function, a function referenced in a variable, or an anonymous function:

```
function callback_named (parameters) { /* ... */ }

callback_variable = function (parameters) { /* ... */ };

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(callback_named);
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(callback_variable);
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (parameters) { /* ... */ });
```

To remove a listener, you call `removeListener` with the same function reference. It's obviously impossible in case on an anonymous function. So, only the first two can be removed:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(callback_named);
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(callback_variable);
```

Note that you can also test for a particular listener:

```
if(chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListener(callback_named)){
  // callback_named is listening
}
```

Or, test if there are listeners at all:

```
if(chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListeners()) {
  // something is listening
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Some APIs allow for even [filtering](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered) and/or additional options, which come after the callback argument. In fact, `webRequest` API is one of such instances, which make the above examples not entirely correct (filters are mandatory for this API). But they answer the essence of the question.

Comment: The source for the sample extension I was looking at is [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/catblock/background.js). In the case of passing it a named function, where would I put the other stuff -- the stuff below the `//filters` comment in the sample?

Comment: Hm. Interesting question. This is an example of what the Event docs call "filtered events". Nothing is really said about their deregistration. Can you try with passing just the named function to `removeListener`? I think it should work.

Comment: I meant when I'm adding the listener. I kind of assumed I would just pass it with the named function to remove.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: So when I call `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(callback_named);` (like you had in the answer), what do I do with the filters? Do they go in the parantheses?

Comment: Read the webRequest docs carefully. In this instance, `addListener` has 3 parameters, so - yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The source of confusion for me here was that in the sample it was an anonymous function -- so the filters went after the closing bracket...