# How to remove a listener in chrome.webRequest API in dart?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart, dart-js-interop

Related to [`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener`? -- How to stop a chrome web listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001428/chrome-webrequest-onbeforerequest-removelistener-how-to-stop-a-chrome-web), I am trying to deregister a listener using dart:js

After invoking `onBeforeRequest.callMethod('removeListener', [callback]);` I notice that the listener is still being called. Furthermore, directly after adding a listener the `hasListener`returns `false` (even thought the listener is being registered).

```
var callback = (map) { /* some code */ };
var filter = new JsObject.jsify({"key": "value"});
var opt_extraInfoSpec = new JsObject.jsify(["extra opt"]);
// chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener
JsObject onBeforeRequest = context['chrome']['webRequest']['onBeforeRequest'];
onBeforeRequest.callMethod('addListener', [callback, filter, opt_extraInfoSpec]);
Logger.root.fine('main(): does callback exist: ${onBeforeRequest.callMethod('hasListener', [callback])}');
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be necessary to follow 100% the `dart:js` recommendations how to use a dart Function in the javascript environment. I guess my problem was that the original dart dynamic function is wrapped automatically in a proxy. Hence the callMethod for addListener used a different proxy object then the callMethod for hasListener, even thought both of them were based on the same original dart object (i.e. callback).

The solution is to use the JsFunction and define the callback as following:

```
var callback = new JsFunction.withThis((that, map) { /* some code */ });
```