# Chrome extension: open a new window in specific user agent

Tags: google-chrome-extension, user-agent

i'm trying to open new incognito window (after clicking something) in different user agent than default (an iPhone 4 user agent for example).

Is it even possible, and if it doesn't, how can I do it in another way?

Sorry for my poor English, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334909/associate-a-custom-user-agent-to-a-specific-google-chrome-page-tab